# Problem with Clojure function

Tags: clojure

everyone, I've started working yesterday on the Euler Project in Clojure and I have a problem with one of my solutions I cannot figure out.

I have this function:

```
(defn find-max-palindrom-in-range [beg end]
  (reduce max
          (loop [n beg result []]
            (if (>= n end)
              result
              (recur (inc n)
                     (concat result
                             (filter #(is-palindrom? %)
                                     (map #(* n %) (range beg end)))))))))
```

I try to run it like this:

```
(find-max-palindrom-in-range 100 1000)
```

and I get this exception:

```
java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
  [Thrown class java.lang.ClassCastException]
```

which I presume means that at some place I'm trying to evaluate an Integer as a function. I however cannot find this place and what puzzles me more is that everything works if I simply evaluate it like this:

```
(reduce max
          (loop [n 100 result []]
            (if (>= n 1000)
              result
              (recur (inc n)
                     (concat result
                             (filter #(is-palindrom? %)
                                     (map #(* n %) (range 100 1000))))))))
```

(I've just stripped down the function definition and replaced the parameters with constants)

Thanks in advance for your help and sorry that I probably bother you with idiotic mistake on my part. Btw I'm using Clojure 1.1 and the newest SLIME from ELPA.

**Edit:** Here is the code to **is-palindrom?**. I've implemented it as a text property of the number, not a numeric one.

```
(defn is-palindrom? [n]
  (loop [num (String/valueOf n)]
    (cond (not (= (first num) (last num))) false
          (<= (.length num) 1) true
          :else (recur (.substring num 1 (dec (.length num)))))))
```

Comment: I think the problem is the `is-palindrom?` function since your `find-max-palindrom-in-range` works for me when I implement the missing `is-palindrom?`

Comment: I've added my code of is-palindrom? to the question.

Comment: A better name for `is-palindom?` in Clojure is: `palindrome?`.

Comment: `(filter #(is-palindrome? %) ...)` is equivalent to `(filter is-palindrome? ...)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code works at my REPL (1.1). I'd suggest that you paste it back at yours and try again -- perhaps you simply mistyped something?

Having said that, you could use this as an opportunity to make the code simpler and more obviously correct. Some low-hanging fruit (don't read if you think it could take away from your Project Euler fun, though with your logic already written down I think it shouldn't):

1. You don't need to wrap `is-palindrome?` in an anonymous function to pass it to `filter`. Just write `(filter is-palindrome? ...)` instead.
2. That `loop` in `is-palindrome?` is pretty complex. Moreover, it's not particularly efficient (`first` and `last` both make a `seq` out of the string first, then `last` needs to traverse all of it). It would be simpler and faster to `(require '[clojure.contrib.str-utils2 :as str])` and use `(= num (str/reverse num))`.
3. Since I mentioned efficiency, using `concat` in this manner is a tad dangerous -- it creates a lazy seq, which might blow up if you pile up two many levels of laziness (this will not matter in the context of Euler 4, but it's good to keep it in mind). If you really need to extend vectors to the right, prefer `into`.
4. To further simplify things, you could consider breaking them apart into a function to filter a given sequence so that only palindromes remain and a separate function to return all products of two three-digit numbers. The latter can be accomplished with e.g.

   ```
   (for [f (range 100 1000)
         s (range 100 1000)
         :when (<= f s)] ; avoid duplication of effort
     (* f s))
   ```

Comment: +1 from the for the great suggestions. I'm fairly new to Clojure and functional programming so I'm aware my style is far from good. It's always nice to hear helpful tips to improve your code. That said I've tried the code many times in the REPL and it simply won't work. And I cannot make heads and tails from the stack trace I get since there is basically nothing from my code in it...

Comment: That's really strange. :-( I'd say give it one more try with a fresh REPL. If it doesn't work -- could you paste the *entirety* of the code you're using and the stack trace somewhere and post a link here?

Comment: Killing my inferior lisp process and starting it again solved the issue. I'm still puzzled what was the original problem, but I thank you for the help.